# MEAN.js - How to configure emails

Tags: node.js, meanjs

Does anyone know how to setup Email in MEAN.js so that you can send password resets?

There is no documentation available from them.

More specifically, what provider will work with the following mailer?

```
...
mailer: {
    from : process.env.MAILER_FROM || '',
    options : {
        service : process.env.MAILER_SERVICE_PROVIDER || '',
        auth : {
            user : process.env.MAILER_EMAIL_ID || '',
            pass : process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD || ''
        }
   }
},
...
```

Comment: Anything wrong with [this](https://masteringmean.com/lessons/51-Sending-an-email-with-Nodejs) or [this documentation](https://nodemailer.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEAN.JS uses [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) as its email platform. To set the email details just edit the config file located in `config/env/` (`development.js` and/or `production.js`).

MEAN.JS also provides a password reset mechanism by default. You can take a look at `modules/users/server/controllers/users/users.password.server.controller.js` and even an helper script located at `scripts/reset-password.js`.

For more details about email providers, creating transports and further email configuration you should take a look at the [nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/) as it was already suggested.